# bash regex in 4.1

Tags: regex, bash

the following code works fine on 3.5 bash but not in 4.1

```
regex='^WORD\-([^(WORD2)][^[:space:]]{1,}$)|(WORD2[[:space:]][^[:space:]]{2,}$)'

if ! [[ $appname =~ $regex ]]    
  then    
    printf "no match"    
    ct_dev_error=$((ct_dev_error+1))    
fi
```

any soliutions? or ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer..... but it doesn't work

Comment: Add sample input to your question which should match and which not.

Comment: No there is no error. It doesn't match anymore, but it should. We check the syntax of an applicationname with it.

Comment: Unless we see samples of matching and non-matching inputs, it is difficult to understand the regex.

Comment: for example WORD-APP --> correct

Comment: another one: WORD-WORD2 APP --> correct

Comment: WORD-BUD APP --> uncorrect

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be simplified to this:

```
regex='^WORD-(WORD2[[:space:]][^[:space:]]{2,}|[^[:space:]]+)$'
```

**Test it:**

```
appname='WORD-APP' && [[ $appname =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
WORD-APP

appname='WORD-BUD APP' && [[ $appname =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"

appname='WORD-WORD2 APP' && [[ $appname =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
WORD-WORD2 APP
```

`[^(WORD2)]` is not actually negating match of `WORD2`. It is actually a **negated character class** and it is basically matching a single character that is NOT one of the characters in this list `(WORD2)`.

Comment: I've tested it. It doesn't work on 4.1  I think it's not the problem of the regex, it's a problem of bash 4.1. The skript ran 2 years on a server without any errors or problems. Two days before we changed our machines and the version of the bash.

Comment: I found the problem. we used special german chars in the Regex (WORD2), but the script was converted in ANSII. I converted the script to utf8 and then it works. The admins changed some configurations when they migrated the applications to the new server...... Thanks for helping. Wish all of yoou a nice day. g Björn